# How can I create an Outlook 2010 Rule to use the AND boolean on Subject keywords

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules, email-filter

I'm using Outlook 2010 and I can only add a Rules query that uses the `OR` boolean operator on a Subject line match. I want to use an `AND` boolean operator but cannot work out how to achieve this.

*My Outlook 2010 Rule query looks like this:*

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
from foo@bar
  and with 'foo' or 'bar' or 'baz' in the subject
assign it to the Foo Bar Baz category
```

*What I really want though is this:*

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
from foo@bar
  and with 'foo' and 'bar' and 'baz' in the subject
assign it to the Foo Bar Baz category
```

I cannot write VBA code, so this is not a solution for me. If anyone knows how to achieve this, I'd be very happy to hear from you.

I note that in the question [Outlook 2010 RULES - How to use OR boolean](https://superuser.com/questions/405545/outlook-2010-rules-how-to-use-or-boolean), which is along the same lines, there's a suggestion that the `AND` boolean operator is the default for Subject match rules in Outlook 2010, but I'm not seeing that behaviour at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use "AND" in Outlook filters?](https://superuser.com/questions/38775/can-i-use-and-in-outlook-filters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I've used in the past for the same problem. It requires a little more work, but there is a way to work around this by using categories.

> The workaround makes use of assigning a category if the first word is
>   found and have a second rule look for another word and the category
>   assigned by the first rule. The second rule can then perform the
>   action if both words are found or add yet another category if you want
>   to check for a 3rd word.

Here is the [article explaining](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/220) how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other simpler way but found one way you can use two keywords in AND condition from Subject line,

check the image at below link for details,

[Two keywords in AND condition from subject line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD0aE.png)