# How to setup a rule in Outlook Web Access, for automatically moving mail which contains multiple words into a specific folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

In Outlook Web Access (OWA), one can setup rules which are applied to all inbound mail, for automatically sorting those mail into specific folders. It seems to be easy to configure a rule which applies to mail which contains *at least one* word in its subject, given a list of words (OR-semantics). In fact, there seem to be even two possibilities to accomplish this: Either we can create multiple rules (one for each word from the list), or we can setup a single rule and use the list of words directly.

However, I cannot find how to setup a rule which applies to mail only if *all* words from a given list are present in the subject (AND-semantics). How can we implement AND-semantics for filter rules in OWA?

I stumbled over [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/38775/can-i-use-and-in-outlook-filters) which however is very old (from 2009). I bet there has been some improvement by now? 13 years have passed, have they added functionality to implement ADD-semantics, given that we even have two ways to implement OR-semantics?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a rule that looks up certain words in the message body, and only if it finds all those words in the message, it will apply a certain action?
If so, this link seems to give you some inspiration:
https://www.msoutlook.info/question/220

Comment: This seems like a workaround which is hard to maintain for complex rules with many words, which may change over time

Comment: Moreover, in OWA, there seems to be no option to create a new category (one can only choose from 6 pre-defined categories).